# is this syntax correct for unpacked array index-wise initialization in system verilog

Tags: multidimensional-array, system-verilog

I have used previously unpacked arrays in different context where every index is initialized in `for` loop, but now i need to initialize them in `module` header and got stuck how to initialize only few indices and remaining should be `default`

```
module phy #(
 parameter NUM_HB = 12
,parameter string STROBE_LOC [NUM_HB-1:0][04-1:0] = '{[0][0]:"TRUE",[0][2]:"TRUE",[1][0]:"TRUE",[1][2]:"TRUE",default:"FALSE"};
)(
   input clk,rst
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for an assignment pattern of a multidimensional array is not straightforward. You need to provide a nested set of arrays fore each dimension.

```
module phy #(
 parameter NUM_HB = 12
  ,parameter string STROBE_LOC [NUM_HB-1:0][04-1:0] = '{
    0:'{0:"TRUE",2:"TRUE",default:""},
    1:'{0:"TRUE",2:"TRUE",default:""},
    default:'{default:""} 
  }
)(
   input clk,rst
);
```

Comment: `parameter string STROBE_LOC [NUM_HB-1:0][04-1:0] = '{
                                                      0:'{0:"TRUE",2:"TRUE"},
                                                      1:'{0:"TRUE",2:"TRUE"},
                                                      default:'{default:""} 
                                                    }` will this work @dave_59

Comment: It does not. Every assignment pattern needs to specify all elements in the array, for each nested array